# PHP repeat a function based on return value

Tags: php

I was wondering how to repeat a function until a certain value is returned. I thought something like this would work but it doesn't.

```
list($db_Total) = getData($db_queryResult); // a random number from a mysqli query result.

function getData($db_Total){
 if($db_Total){
   while($arr = mysqli_fetch_array){
      $db_Total = $arr['prize']; // set db_Total to database query amount
  }
 }
}
if($db_Total>=300){
 echo "is equal or higher than 300";

  while($db_Total >= 300){  // loop until you get a smaller result
   list($db_Total) = getData($db_queryResult);
  }
}elseif($db_Total <= 300){
  echo "is lower than 300";
}
```

I guess the simpliest way to say it is, I would like to just run a function once, if that function returns a value higher than I don't want, I want to run that function again until it does... is that possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (($db_Total = getData($db_queryResult)) >= 300) {
  echo "is equal or higher than 300";
}
echo "is lower than 300";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are just a few of the errors in that code:

- `$arr = mysqli_fetch_array` should be `$arr = mysqli_fetch_array($db_queryResult)`
- however many times you call `mysqli_fetch_array` it won't change the result, since you've already run the actual SQL once
- or did you mean to just look at one row of a multiple-row result each time the `getData` function was called - in which case you don't want the `while` loop that's inside that function, which will consume all rows from the database result
- the `getData` function never returns anything (no `return` statement)
- the `getData` function seems to be given a DB result set, but calls it `$db_Total` and does nothing other than check that it's not false-y (`if($db_Total)`)
- `list($foo) = bar()` is used when `bar()` returns an array of several separate items; not sure why you think you need it here
- `elseif($db_Total <= 300){` should just be `else`
- beware of infinite loops - are you absolutely guaranteed to eventually get a number lower than 300?